# Exit option with my menu in my window

Tags: java, menu, jframe, system, jmenubar

The code is here:
I don't think the System.exit(); is working properly.
Am I using the wrong method or what?

```
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
setJMenuBar(menuBar);

JMenu mnRWindow = new JMenu("RWindow");
menuBar.add(mnRWindow);

JMenuItem mntmMore = new JMenuItem("More");
mnRWindow.add(mntmMore);

JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
mntmExit.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.exit(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
});
mnRWindow.add(mntmExit);
```

Comment: Yeah, just a note.
My program seems to want to exit but I can't seem to terminate the JFrame it self.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a MouseListener with a JMenuItem.

A `JMenuItem` is designed to be used with an `ActionListener`. Read the section from the swing tutorial on How to Use Menus for more information and working examples.

Also, DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE is NOT a value you should be using for the System.exit(...) method. That variable should only be used with the `setDefaultCloseOperation(...)` method of the frame. Just use a "0" for the value.

Comment: But I put 0 in there and it too doesn't do anything.

Comment: @brken11, There is no trick to using that method. Did you add a System.out.println(...) statement to you code to make sure the code in your ActionListener is executed? Update your question with a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.